# BeagleBone Black as external processing unit for Robotics

Tags: linux, export, real-time, robotics, beagleboneblack

I need to execute a set of commands on a robot, the robot already have an Mini-ITX PC attached to it, but it is slow and real-time results are not satisfactory.

I would like to use a external BeagleBone as the processing unit, but how do I configure the setup to process/compile code on the BeagleBone and execute on the robot?

I believe the 'export' IP utility is something I need?

Comment: There are several ways to compile code for the Beaglebone. 1. Use the software provided through Cloud9 2. Use traditional Linux-Shell/Bash commands 3. Cross-Compile on another machine and then copy the files to the bone; To get real-time results from the bone where every instruction takes approximately 5ns, you'll need to use the bone's programmable real-time unit (PRU).

Answer (score 0):

What kind of robot you would like to control? What kind of hardware you are using to directly drive the robots hardware?

BeagleBone is a noice choice for embedded linux applications. But it's a little bit tricky to support real-time. Therefore you need access to the PRU (Programmable Real-Time Unit).